# Initialise ArrayList<ArrayList<Int>> with a size in kotlin

Tags: java, arrays, list, kotlin, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to initialise a list with a size in the constructor. But the size of my list is 0.

```
val seqList = ArrayList<ArrayList<Int>>(N) // This has the Problem
val queries = ArrayList<Query>(Q) // This works like a charm
```

I have both `N` and `Q` set as non zero inputs from the user lets say 
`N = 100` and `Q = 100`

While debugging my code I found out that, `queries.size() = 100` but `seqList.size() = 0`

Is my assumption incorrect, that `seqList` should also have been initialized with `N ArrayList<Int>` objects.

Comment: Are you sure that queries.size() is non zero? That constructor sets the capacity, not the size.

Comment: I was putting the breakpoint at the wrong point, you are right. The constructor does not set the size, but the capacity :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your assumption isn't correct, I'm afraid.

Quoted from the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/index.html) of `ArrayList`:

> Provides a `MutableList` implementation,
> which uses a resizable array as its backing storage.
>
> This implementation **doesn't provide a way to manage capacity**, as
> backing JS array is resizeable itself. There is no speed advantage to
> pre-allocating array sizes in JavaScript, so this implementation does
> not include any of the capacity and "growth increment" concepts.

The constructor particularly:

> ```
> ArrayList(initialCapacity = 0))
> ```
>
> **Creates an empty ArrayList.**

An **empty** `ArrayList` is created, thus providing 100 as an argument will not create elements inside the list.